# How to perform two functions in a single for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanna split a sentence and also replace quotes from it. I did:

```
sentences = read_data.split('\n')

sentences_no_quotes = [sentence.replace('"', '') for sentence in sentences]

splited_sentences = [sentence.split(',') for sentence in sentences_no_quotes]
```

How can I do it in a single line? any suggestions! Thanks for the help

Comment: `splitted_sentences = [sentence.replace('"', '').split(',') for sentence in sentences]`

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to parse CSV data or some other well known data format…?

Comment: @Efferalgan thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it, it's straightforward.

```
splited_sentences = [sentence.split(',') for sentence in
                     [sentence.replace('"', '') for sentence in
                      read_data.split('\n')]]
```

Probably you'd better use generators instead of lists but that's beyond your question.